# .btn btn-primary * { visibility: hidden; } is not working

Tags: html, css

I want to hide few buttons to print so I am using this CSS code but it is not working still button are showing in print HTML code is

```css
.btn btn-primary * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="control" style="display: none">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toEmail()">Send to Mail</button>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `.btn.btn-primary *`?

Comment: Yes both way it is not working @HaoWu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these two classes are written in the same button tag. This means that the selector should look like this, and **without** `*`:

```
.btn.btn-primary {}
```

Since `*` is a reference to all children of the current element.

In this example, I removed `display: none` from `id="control"` to visually understand that the code works.

```css
.btn.btn-primary {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="control"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toEmail()">Send to Mail</button>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button></div>
```